# How i can use custom field without render in DataTable

Tags: asp.net-core, datatable, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Some of the columns on the table wanna use without render it. For example, table has five columns which I want define first and last columns inside TBODY. Column 2-3-4 must render via DataTable

I've tried set null, data:'' , type:'html' for that columns but they didn't work.
Always give an error about row 0.

```
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">
                #
            </th>
            <th scope="col">
                <label class="control-label">Loc</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label class="control-label">Date</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label class="control-label">Per</label>
            </th>
            <th>
                <label class="control-label">Type</label>
            </th>
            <th scope="col">#</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
            foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Always True
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Some partial views
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </tbody>
</table>

<script>
    var table = $('#dataTable').dataTable({
        "processing": true,
        "serverSide": true,
        "info": true,
        "stateSave": true,
        responsive: {
            details: false
        },
        lengthMenu:
        [
            [10, 20, 50, -1], [10, 20, 50, "All"]
        ],
        ajax: {
            "url": "myUrl.json",
            "type": "POST",
            "contentType": 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            "dataType": 'json',
            'data': function(data) {
                return JSON.stringify(data);
            },
            "error": function(xhr, error, thrown) {
                alert("error");
            }
        },
        "columns": [
            {
                //this column get from TBODY,
            }
            {
                data: 'loc',
                responsivePriority: 1
            },
            {
                data: 'date',
                responsivePriority: 5
            },
            {
                data: 'per',
                responsivePriority: 3
            },
            {
                data: 'type',
                responsivePriority: 4
            },
            {
                //This column get from TBODY because there is a partial view
            }
        ],
        rowId: "id",
        "order": [[1, "asc"]],
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It's not possible. maybe preprocess your json file server side to include additional data and/or use a templating library to render your partial view client side

Comment: Actualy, i have problem about PartialView. I control permissions to link in partial view. So if i use DataTable render property, render body will be too many line code